# how to send the array to servlet and save to the database

Tags: java, javascript

i had a function it contains an array.my problem is how to send the values which are in array to java.class file

this is my code

```
function sales_det(){

        var salDet=document.getElementsByClassName("sales_details");
        //console.log(salDet.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < salDet.length; i++) {
            var sal=salDet[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
            window["array_"+i] = [];
 window["array_"+i].push(sal[0].textContent,sal[1].textContent,sal[2].textContent,sal[3].textContent);

           console.log(window["array_"+i]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: If you're talking about sending an array from a browser to your server, the the two things you need to research are Ajax (a means of sending data to a server from a browser) and JSON (a text format commonly used for sending data from browsers to servers or vice/versa).

Answer (score 0):

you can store it as attribute in some scope. and retrieve it in servlet. like this way

request.setAttribute("myarray",arrayObject);

request.getAttribute("myarray"). // here not forget to caste it. because it store as Object only

Answer (score 0):

You can create a comma separated string of array values, get it using request.getParameter and split it in servlet using strObj.split(",")

Answer (score 0):

Pass the array along with the request using form submit or an ajax call then at server side retrieve the value using the following code:

`String array[] = request.getParameterValues("arrayName");`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. create a function in js that returns your array.

   function arrayFromJS(){
   //return your array
   }
2. from html

   //input type="hidden" name="arrayfromjs" value=arrayFromJS()
3. in servlet you can use:

   request.getParameter("arrayfromjs");